# Where can I find admin-header.php file online?

Tags: wp-admin, installation

I am using Wordpress for my website. I was  working on CPANEL yesterday and was browsing `public-html/wp-admin folder` under the `File manager`.

There were many files and I accidentally deleted the `admin-header.php` file.

Where can I get an another copy of that file so that I can upload it to the same folder from where it got deleted?

Comment: ...wordpress.org? Voting to close, unless you can somehow salvage this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't see a download link on the Github page for downloading single files(i don't use it so maybe i'm just not seeing it).

Alternatively you can download single files for WordPress from trac.

**Example:**
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/admin-header.php

Scroll to the bottom of the page(or hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key),
look for the text "**Download in other formats:**"
click the "**Original Format**" link below that text to download the single file.

Can't hurt to have options right.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Get it from [here](https://github.com/wordpress/wordpress/tree/master/wp-admin)

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't do this type of things but you can do one thing

go to wordpress.org -> download -> release archives

download your current version in local host

extract it and then go to wordpress -> wp-admin -> admin-header.php

or maybe wordpress -> wp-admin -> includes -> admin-header.php

and upload it to server